# Firebase check if child value in node A matches child value in node B

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a the below data structure in my Firebase database, I am trying to search the 'users' node by 'phoneNum' to see if there are any matches when I add a new player in the 'players' node

I think I am listening on the wrong node or using the addChildEventListener incorrectly as at the moment when I add a player with the same number it returns the else statement '***NOT FOUND***'

Any help much appreciated

[Image of datastructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rUK3.png)

Code below

```
    usersDatabase = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users");
private void checkIfPlayerIsUser(final String phoneNum){
  //  String ph = phoneNum.substring(phoneNum.length() - 8);
    usersDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "****NULLL****", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else if(dataSnapshot.getValue().equals(phoneNum)){

                // player added is in user database
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "****PLAYER FOUND****", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "****NOT FOUND****", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this method below. i use it in running application to check if username is taken before or not. i hope it help.

```
  void checkIfPlayerIsUser(final String phoneNum) {
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = 
         FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNum)) {
        final Query phoneNumReference = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("phoneNum").equalTo(phoneNum);

        ValueEventListener phoneNumValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "****PLAYER FOUND****", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "****NOT FOUND****", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };

            phoneNumReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(phoneNumValueEventListener);


    } else {
         Log.e("Error","phoneNum is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Moh Nage, trying this now. Where do I clare 'phoneNumRefernce and what type is it?

Comment: it's type is Query "import com.google.firebase.database.Query;" 
define it in the method or as class field as you want.

Comment: thanks ! 
It is also saying 'cannot resolve symbol' for both mDatabaseReference and when passing userNameValueEventListener in this line

         `phoneNumReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(usernameValueEventListener);`

Comment: DatabaseReference is the reference for the node you want to search in.

Comment: you're welcome , feel free to up vote and accept it as an answer :)

Comment: Hi mohnage, thanks again for helping me. Just a quick question, how would I return the value of the found datasnapshot? And once I have found a 'user' with the same 'phoneNum' is it possible to get the key id for that user?

Comment: you should add your userId inside each user node . and you should prepare your Pojo of User class contains the fields that you want. after you found your user use this line to return it's value " User mUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class); "

Comment: Thanks, man. I have set up my user class to get the uId and added the user, but when I use the line `User mUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);`

my output is as follows:
com.name.appname.User@78bdd64

Comment: When I use
`User mUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        String ph = mUser.getPhoneNum();`
It is returning a Null value for ph

Comment: make sure that all your class field matches the keys inside your node

Comment: yes class fields all match up with the node data. So not sure what is going on

Comment: open new question and post your code and send me the link here

Comment: dones, thanks again man. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758597/firebase-datasnapshot-null-values

Comment: i answered you there. check this as answer as it met your question here . and let's take the discussion there.

Comment: thanks man, I went down the rabbit hole myself and managed to do it another way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DatabaseReference` is wrong. In order to get the correct `phoneNum` you need to use this code:

```
usersDatabase = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(userId);
```

In which the `userId` is the unique key generated by the `push()` method.

And than to check please use:

```
DatabaseReference usersDatabase = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userKey = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference userKeyDatabase =  mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(userKey);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "****NULLL****", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else if(dataSnapshot.child("phoneNum").getValue().equals(phoneNum)){
                        // player added is in user database
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "****PLAYER FOUND****", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "****NOT FOUND****", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            userKeyDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex, this is where I am running into some problems. 
I would need to be able to search all existing users for this child node 'phoneNum'  so I would not know what userId is as it could be any of them.
Is something like this possible? A for loop running through the data snapshot maybe?

Comment: Thanks again Alex, looks like it should work but no luck . I was getting a Null Pointer error and now after editing the 'if' to (dataSnapshot.child("phoneNum").getValue() == null) 

It keeps returning to say its a Null Value

Comment: First try to log `userKey` and see if is null. If is not, check the second, `dataSnapshot.child("phoneNum").getValue()` and see if is null. To log, you can use the following code: `Log.d("Tag", userKey);` Keep me posted.

Comment: userKey seems to get the values ok, I checked dataSnapshot.child("phoneNum").getValue() and they are all null values

Comment: If the `userKey` is not null, than the `userKeyDatabase` is also `not null`, because is pointing to exact user. Try to comment the `if, else if, else` statement and try to log only `dataSnapshot.child("phoneNum").getValue()`. Is still null?

Comment: Might have done something wrong, but it is still showing as null even when I comment out the 'if, else if, else block'

 `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            Log.d("Tag", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("phoneNum").getValue()));`

Comment: Please use: `Log.d("Tag", dataSnapshot.child("phoneNum").getValue().toString());` Still null?

Comment: Changed it to the above and now getting this error: 

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference`

thanks for looking at it btw Alex

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that it did log a non null value though, so not sure what the problem is!

Comment: So you say the `userKey` is not null. When you try log those id's, you get the unique id's but when you try to log the second `danaSnapshop`, you get null, that's correct?

Comment: User key is not null.  and when I try log the second data snapshot with the if/ else commented out I get a Java.Null.PointerException with this code

`public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d("Tag", dataSnapshot.child("phoneNum").getValue().toString());`

and null values with this line of code

`public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
Log.d("Tag", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("phoneNum").getValue()));`

Comment: Please verify the second `DatabaseReference` to be correct. Are you sure your field `phoneNum` exists in your database and has a value? If everything is alright with this, than i'll need to take a look at your code. Anything else is wrong.